# Laravel 5, some routes 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Part of my Nginx file

```
    server {
listen 80;
#listen 443 ssl;
server_name bla.com;
root "/bla/bla";

#disable_symlinks off;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    #rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    #fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    #fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    #fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    #fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    #fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    #fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

For example, this route:

```
     Route::group(['prefix' => '/api/v1'/*, 'middleware' => 'auth'*/],              

         function () {
             Route::get('/music/groups', 'Music\GroupsController@index');
         }
     });
```

Gives me 404

But if I add this route .. it works (hence the extra C):

```
   Route::get('/musicc/groups', 'Music\GroupsController@index');
```

Can it have anyhting to do with the same name ? Music and music. The controller is in App\Http\Controllers\Music\GroupsController

Namespace is App\Http\Controllers\Music;

Comment: are you getting 404 when accessing `yourdomain/api/v1/music/groups` and it works when you declare it as `musicc/groups` outside of the group?

Comment: its in the same group, only difference is the extra c, i thought it was maybe cached. Tried every cache thingy of Laravel I could find, but that didn't help.

Comment: @MinardusvanderKooi What I would do: 1. Execute `php artisan route:list` and see if your not working route is included. 2. To totally rule out that it has something to do with your nginx config use the webserver included in Laravel by executing `php artisan serve` and see if it is working, or not.

Comment: It works when I use         php artisan serve, thanks for the tip, than it must have something to do with the Nginx config. Im going to dive in this, this evening.